# Applied AI | Form Recognizer Studio - The Custom Model project could not be found. 404 Error after Custom model project creation

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

Creating a new project using the custom model option and getting an error saying "The Custom Model project could not be found."
It was working till last month.
Create API is successful
https://formrecognizer.appliedai.azure.com/custom-model/projects
but when trying to load with project id URL it returns 404.

[image: After Custom Model Project creation]

Comment: I have the same problem if I need to add another user to see the model

Comment: yep same I created a project but can't get any other users to see it